How to Compile eBPF Programs Without Debug Symbols and Attach BTF Information?
I'm trying to compile eBPF programs without using the -g option but still need to attach BTF (BPF Type Format) information to the resulting object file. I'm developing an LLVM ir pass and I don't want to deal up to now with debug informations.
I'm looking for a detailed, step-by-step guide on how to:
Compile an eBPF program without including debug symbols.
Attach BTF information to the compiled eBPF object file.
Any advice or example commands would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Here's what I've tried so far:

Compiling the eBPF program with clang -target bpf -o prog.o prog.c
Attempting to attach BTF information manually using various tools, but without success. For exampleI tried to llvm-objcopy sections from another compiled (with debug symbols) eBPF program, but verifier rejected the program.


How about trying the reverse approach? You can compile with debug information (-g) and then remove what you don't want:
clang -g -target bpf -o prog.o prog.c
llvm-objcopy --remove-section=.debug_abbrev \
    --remove-section=.debug_info --remove-section=.debug_str_offsets \
    --remove-section=.debug_str --remove-section=.debug_addr \
    --remove-section=.debug_frame --remove-section=.debug_line \
    --remove-section=.debug_line_str --remove-section=.debug_loclists \
    --remove-section=.debug_rnglists \
    prog.o prog.stripped.o

In my case (Clang 18), this results in the same ELF as without debug information, except I have 4 additional sections for BTF: .BTF, .rel.BTF, .BTF.ext, and .rel.BTF.ext.

because I'm modifiyng the IR and I don't want to deal with debug informations for prototyping
